# hole filling algorthim for VB 6

Tags: vba, image-processing, vb6

I'm trying to find a way to implement fill holes algorithm for binary image in VB 6.0. I found these sites so far

http://answers.opencv.org/question/9863/fill-holes-of-a-binary-image/
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html

I'm totally confused by the algorithm to find holes. Can someone please refer me to a better site or simple code so can assist me to implement the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to fill holes in the binary image with a morphological closing operation that typically consists of a dilation followed by an erosion. A side effect of these operations is a small distortion of the shape. [morhplogyEx()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#void%20morphologyEx%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20op,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20iterations,%20int%20borderType,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29) with parameter MORPH_CLOSE will do it for you in one operation.

A more sophisticated algorithm to use is [flood fill](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#cv.FloodFill) which will return the area of the hole as well as will mark it with a specified color. It starts at a seed area specified with a Point seedPoint.

I personally prefer to invert the image contrast and find holes as small blobs or connected components. I then erase blobs with a certain size and invert the image again. OpenCV has a simple [blob detector.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=blob#SimpleBlobDetector%20%3a%20public%20FeatureDetector)